# Which specific sanitizing functions are used on Wikimedia URLs?

Tags: php, wikipedia, sanitization

I'm writing a simple query to find urls on commons.wikimedia.org but i can't seem to get around which specific sanitizing rules i should use to get the exact name files used there.

Eg.: The flag of Ivory Coast is listed in french as `Drapeau_de_la_Côte_d%27Ivoire` so i get it that apostrophes are being sanitized but the regular `ô` isn't. I've seen a lot of other file names with special characters preserved.

Is it safe to assume that all special chars are preserved and all punctuation and/or non-letters are sanitized?

Comment: Browser does that, not wikepedia. Browser sends urls in ascii-safe symbols only, but shows them in more friendly way specially for users

Comment: so there's no sanitization whatsoever happening on their side?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of sanitization you mean, but for that part they just send the data encoded in %nn (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_C%C3%B4te_d'Ivoire) and your browser decodes it back

Comment: I think it's called encoding not sanitazion. IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia uses all the url escaped in `%nnnn` format (according all URL RFCs), and your browser does the final work for you, just to have the urls more friendly.

So even though my chrome shows `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Côte_d'Ivoire` url, originally it was `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_C%C3%B4te_d'Ivoire`